# Is this a valid approach to using Paypal IPN?

Tags: php, paypal

This is the pseudo code that i will implement:

```
    include("../../application/config/db_config.php");

if ($payment_status == 'Completed') 
{
    if customer/order details exist in table
    { 
        change payment_status to completed, create PDF and Email to customer_email.
    }
    elseif customer/order details not exist in table
    {
        insert details into table, create PDF and Email to customer_email.
    }
}
else if($payment_status == 'Denied' || $payment_status == 'Failed' || $payment_status == 'Voided') 
{
    Do Nothing.
}
else if($payment_status == 'In-Progress' || $payment_status == 'Pending' || $payment_status == 'Processed') 
{
    insert into table, customer details/order details.                  
}
```

This is not including validation. I just want to know if i am thinking about this on the right track.

I still need to retrieve customer input as a variable before payment, would it be best to save to the database before user pays? or is it possible to send this variable accross paypal and have it return the variable in the ipn?

Thanks Guys

Comment: approach seems fine, but its not a good S.O question

Comment: I think this is a fine type of SO question: validating the structure/approach to a problem with pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, triggering fulfullment upon receipt of successful payment IPN is a solid approach (as long as the fulfillment is not intended as instant/inline, so the customer is sitting at their screen waiting for the IPN processing). So at a high level, yes you are approaching this correctly.

That said, a few pointers about what you have written:

1) it seems unusual to have so many branches at IPN time. Why would you be getting payments where you have order information sometimes, but not other times? Is the former case for when the IPN is for the completion of a delayed payment? If so, see #2

2) I would recommend always storing the order somewhere before the payment step, thus making the appropriate IPN response always a status update rather than sometimes a write, other times a status update. There's virtually no cost to writing an unpaid order to your db, and some potential benefits (e.g. the ability to analyze what/why people are not completing; perhaps even to follow up on incomplete orders). It also simplifies your life to AVOID trying to pass a lot of data through your payment processor. Just pass through an order#/invoice#/whatever and keep the rest on your side. This reduces your integration cost and gives you more flexibility going forward (e.g. if you added/changed processors).

3) I don't think your handling PayPal payment statuses is exactly right, but I presume that is a detail you will get to at implementation time.

4) You don't mention whether you intend to use payments or authorizations, but the industry best practice for delayed fulfillment is to authorize, fullfill, then capture. Especially if your fulfillment may include additional user interactions (I don't understand your last paragrpah "I still need to...") this may help clean up the flow a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your input, there a few points I had trouble understanding but will look into it. When you say update status you mean the table right? Such as order status completed.

Comment: Just to confirm my process is like this. When the user clicks buy now the order is placed into table with order status awaiting payment, as well as another custom field of need when payment is complete. When payment is complete I need to reference the order id which I will send via custom variable to paypal. Upon verification order status will change to completed,or depending if the order is still pending. Upon order complete and email will send a specific attachment to said payers email.

Comment: Yes to your first question, and the description in your second comment sounds about as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach is wrong, there are no checks for a verified response and/or receiver details.

```
// is response VERIFIED?
// is the receiver email correct?
// is the payment type correct?
// is the transaction id new or existing?
    // transaction id is new, insert
    // transaction id is old, update status/pending reason/paypal fee/total
```

Please checkout https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php for a sample.

Comment: Thanks David. I didn't really think about this validation I will look into this. Thanks for your input on this.

Comment: Ah -- I took the statement "This is not including validation" in the original question to mean the omission was intentional, but David is completely correct that PayPal's IPN validation step should be in the solution.